# Approximation algorithm for non-bipartite Euclidean matching

Tags: graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms, matching

What is the current best (in terms of running time) (1+\epsilon)-approximation algorithm (both randomized and deterministic) for non-bipartite Euclidean (in higher dimension) matching? There are recent works on the bipartite version (as for instance https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.03875.pdf). Among the non-bipartite, I have found a relatively earlier result of Vardarajan & Aggarwal ([https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/~alon/papers/approx-match.pdf](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/%7Ealon/papers/approx-match.pdf)) which works only in the Euclidean plane. Is there any improved algorithm?

Comment: Further what is the status on the doubling metric?